# Do launchDaemons keep running on iPhone Lock Screen?

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I need an answer to a simple question. Do the launchDaemons keep running even if iPhone Screen is Locked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES, as i got from some other sources.

The LaunchDaemons keep on working even if iPhone Screen is Locked !!!

Comment: They do run, but if the device goes to sleep, they will be paused (just like when a computer goes into sleep mode)

Comment: Correct. I checked this behavior, they do get paused when iphone goes to deep sleep